# What should be the resolution/dimension of an image shown as an Interstitial (fullscreen) ad on smartphones/tablets?

Tags: mobile, advertisement, fullscreen

I want to show an image as a fullscreen ad. 
What should be the image's size and pixel density, so that the same image can be used for Android and iOS phones/tablets.

I did some research and [Google Admob's doc](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6177172?hl=en) shows that they follow two different sizes - 480x320 for phone and 768x1024 for tablets.

Although I trust Google, but please let me know about other details like DPI of the image.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you trust google?

Comment: @DimitraMiha :) we all trust google..i raised this question for any other details to be taken care like image's DPI,etc..see my update..

Comment: Especially in the way you're displaying it (to fill the screen), DPI is not a _property of the image_ -- it's determined by _the particular device_ it is displayed on.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use one image for all smartphones and tablets.

**Apple** uses @1x, @2x and @3x for different screen sizes and resolutions (phone/tablet and pre-retina/retina).

> iOS uses a coordinate system to place content onscreen. This
>   coordinate system is based on measurements in points, which map to
>   pixels in the display. On a standard-resolution screen, one point
>   (1/72 of an inch) is equal to one pixel. High-resolution screens have
>   a higher pixel density. Because there are more pixels in the same
>   amount of physical space, there are more pixels per point. As a
>   result, high-resolution displays require images with more pixels.

Source: [Human Interface Guidelines: Image Size and Resolution](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/)

**Material Design (Android)** talks about density-independent pixels (dp).

> A dp is equal to one physical pixel on a screen with a density of 160.
>   To calculate dp:
>
> dp = (width in pixels * 160) / screen density

Source: [Units & measurements](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-density-independent-pixels-dp)

To help you out there are many online tools and tutorials. You can also setup documents and templates in Photoshop and Sketch.

Comment: thanks for your answer..so u mean to say that I will need two different size image like Google advises..and the images needs to have 72 DPI right?

Comment: Check out this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365112/what-dpi-resolution-is-used-for-an-iphone-app